# cannot run webpack with react-redux Provier

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, webpack-4

i have simple project that using react js with react-redux

i have issue with webpack and react-redux  
when i want to build my project i get this error :

```
$ webpack --mode development
Hash: b70fd5668fd64f56b8f6
Version: webpack 4.44.2
Time: 82ms
Built at: 05/03/2021 2:05:34 PM
                         Asset      Size  Chunks                         Chunk Names
bundle.b70fd5668fd64f56b8f6.js  4.11 KiB    main  [emitted] [immutable]  main
Entrypoint main = bundle.b70fd5668fd64f56b8f6.js
[./src/index.js] 341 bytes {main} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/index.js 11:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
| ReactDOM.render(
>   <Provider store={store}>
|     {/* <React.StrictMode> */}
|       <BrowserRouter>
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

i tried very solutions but it did'nt worked and i really need to solve it 
this is my **webpack.config.js** :

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.[hash].js"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.scss'],
    modules: [
      'node_modules'
    ],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
              presets: ["react,es2015"]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "style-loader css-loader sass-loader",
          options: {
              presets: ["react,es2015"]
          }
        }
      },
    ]
  }
};
```

i created the babelrc file too and install **babel-presets-react** and **babel-presets-es2015** by --dev

the **.babelrc** file :

```
{
  "presets": [
  "react",
  "es2015"
 ]
}
```

any help ?